# Thread blocks during channel registration

Tags: java, netty

After my application runs for a while, my threads get stuck while waiting for a Channel to register.

Here is the code:

```
bootstrap = new Bootstrap()
    .group(new EpollEventLoopGroup())
    .channel(EpollSocketChannel.class)
    .option(ChannelOption.ALLOCATOR, PooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT)
    .handler(new MyChannelInitializer(this));

ChannelFuture registerFuture = bootstrap.register().sync();
Channel channel = registerFuture.channel();

//Do other stuffs

channel.connect(...).addListener(...);
```

After running for some time, the threads block during the `sync()`.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Name: worker-thread-1
State: WAITING on io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise@17ba258
Total blocked: 37  Total waited: 43,574

Stack trace: 
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.await(DefaultPromise.java:231)
io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.await(DefaultChannelPromise.java:131)
io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.await(DefaultChannelPromise.java:30)
io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.sync(DefaultPromise.java:337)
io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.sync(DefaultChannelPromise.java:119)
io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.sync(DefaultChannelPromise.java:30)
...
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)  
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Why is my thread blocked here? There is no connection yet, only creating a Channel and registering it to the event loop.

Comment: You should take a thread-dump and check if you block the EventLoop somehow.